# How does Visual Studio Code handle the fputs statement for File I/O in "r+" mode?

Tags: c, string, file-io, fputs

I have written a code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("lets.txt","r+");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        char ch,ch1;
        while(!feof(fp))
        {
           ch= fgetc(fp);
           printf("%c",ch);
        }
        printf("\n\nYou want to write something? (1/0)");
        int n;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n==1)
        {
            fputs("Jenny",fp);
            ch1 = fgetc(fp);
            printf("%c\n", ch1);
            while(ch1 != EOF)
            {
                ch1=fgetc(fp);
                printf("%c",ch1);
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
        else{
            printf("File Closed ");
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to insert a string inside an already existing file "lets.txt"
[image: The original text file]

but when I run this code, this is shown in the Terminal
[image: Photo of Terminal on running the code]

I was expecting this to just put Jenny into the final file but it's also adding other text which was present before it and lots of NULL.
Is this because of something like temporary memory storage or something like that or just some mistake in the code?
[image: [![no idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQmpK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQmpK.png)]

Comment: Read this: [**Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I changed the condition for the while loop to this simple form-                
        ch  = fgetc(fp);
        while(ch != EOF)
But it is still showing the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the lines

```
char ch,ch1;
while(!feof(fp))
{
    ch= fgetc(fp);
    printf("%c",ch);
}
```

are wrong.

If you want `ch` to be guaranteed to be able to represent the value `EOF` and also want to be able to distinguish it from every possible character code, then you must store the return value of `fgetc` in an `int`, not a `char`. Please note that `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75201013/12149471) for more information on this issue.

Also, the function `feof` will only return a non-zero value (i.e. true) if a previous read operation **has already** failed due to end-of-file. It does not provide any indication of whether the next read operation **will** fail. This means that if `fgetc` returns `EOF`, you will print that value as if `fgetc` were successful, which is wrong. See the following question for further information on this issue:

[Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/12149471)

For the reasons stated above, I suggest that you change these lines to the following:

```
int ch, ch1;

while ( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
{
    printf( "%c", ch );
}
```

Another issue is that when a file is opened in update mode (i.e. it is opened with a `+` in the mode string, for example `"r+"` as you are doing), you cannot freely change between reading and writing. According to [§7.21.5.3 ¶7 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7),

- output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and
- input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.

If you break any of these rules, than your program will be invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means that anything can happen, which includes the possibility that you get invalid output.

For this reason, I suggest that you change the lines

```
fputs("Jenny",fp);
ch1 = fgetc(fp);
```

to:

```
fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_CUR );
fputs("Jenny",fp);
fflush( fp );
ch1 = fgetc(fp);
```

In contrast to the line `fflush( fp );`, which is absolutely necessary, the line `fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_CUR );` actually isn't necessary according to the rules stated above, because you encountered end-of-file. But it probably is a good idea to keep that line anyway, for example in case you later change your program to stop reading for some other reason besides end-of-file. In that case, that line would be required.

Comment: Thanks bro. Now the code is working perfectly fine. I have a query tho 
do we have to follow these same set of instructions for w+ and a+ modes also or is there some variation for them ?

Comment: Yes. Any mode with both reading and writing enabled, when you switch between reading and writing.

Comment: @Tar: Unless you are programming for a specific platform, I suggest that you use [this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) for the function `fopen`. That documentation also specifies the rules that I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

> Re: "I changed the condition for the while loop to this simple form-
> ch = fgetc(fp); while(ch != EOF) But it is still showing the same
> result.

---

**The value returned by `getchar()` must be stored in an `int`:**

```
ch= fgetc(fp);
```

`ch` has been declared as a `char`. Storing the value in a `char` makes testing for `EOF` unreliable. C17 states that `EOF` has a negative int value. On some implementations, `char` is `unsigned`, hence it can't represent negative values.

On implementations where the type `char` is signed, assuming `EOF` is defined as `-1` (which is the case on most implementations), it's impossible to distinguish `EOF` from the character code `255` (which would be stored as the value `-1` in a `char`, but as `255` in an `int`).

From the man page:

> fgetc(), getc(), and getchar() return the character read as an
> unsigned char cast to an ***int*** or EOF on end of file or error.

It further states:

> If the integer value returned by getchar() is stored into a
> variable of type char and then compared against the integer
> constant EOF, the comparison may never succeed, because sign-
> extension of a variable of type char on widening to integer is
> implementation-defined.

which is relevant to `fgetc` as well.

---

**Possible fix:**

Declare `ch` as an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the file pointer when switching between read and write. The [MSVC man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-170) says about `fopen`

> However, when you switch from reading to writing, the input operation must encounter an `EOF` marker. If there's no `EOF`, you must use an intervening call to a file positioning function. The file positioning functions are `fsetpos`, `fseek`, and `rewind`. When you switch from writing to reading, you must use an intervening call to either `fflush` or to a file positioning function.